# SQLAlchemy many-to-many check if object exists

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a User Class and an Event class with a many-to-many relationship representing users being "members" of the event.  When a new user registers for an event I need to check if they are already a member.

```
class User(db.Model,UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(),primary_key =True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(50))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(50))
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), index = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), index = True)
    create_date = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    questions = db.relationship('Question',backref='user',lazy='dynamic')
    events = db.relationship('Event',backref='owner',lazy='dynamic')


memberships = db.relationship('Event',secondary=memberships,backref= 
 db.backref('members',lazy='dynamic'))


class Event(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'event'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(),primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    event_code = db.Column(db.String(30))
    description = db.Column(db.Text())
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer(),db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    #owner = db.relationship("User",back_populates="events")
    questions = db.relationship('Question',backref='event',lazy='dynamic')

    moderate_questions = db.Column(db.Boolean,nullable=False,default=True)
    allow_anonymous = db.Column(db.Boolean,nullable=False,default=True)
```

I am then trying to test if a User is already part of the "members" collection created by the relationship.  The function below does not work.

```
def is_member(self, member_id):
    return Event.query.filter(Event.members.any
        ('user_id' == member_id)).filter(Event.members.any('event_id'== self.id)).all()
```

My question is.  How do you test if a value relationship exists. in a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: And so, what is your question? 
You present some nice code, make some nice afirmations, but one can't even knw if what you've done works or not, but by trying to replicate your code by configuring a full Python project with database access.

Comment: I am trying to get the is_member() function to work.  As it is written above it does not.  I can write the code to iterate through the list of members but I can't figure out how to write a statement that checks if the join exists.